# Calculating a Date Using Decimal Value in SQL

Tags: sql, datetime, decimal

I have the following fields in a SQL Database:

```
@EstimatedRequiredTimeHours DECIMAL(18,2) = NULL, 
@ScheduledStartDate SMALLDATETIME = NULL,
@ScheduledEndDate  SMALLDATETIME = NULL
```

I need to calculate the `@ScheduledEndDate` by adding the `@EstimatedRequiredTimeHours` to the `@ScheduledStartDate`.

I'm not entirely sure how to do this, `DATEADD()` doesn't seem like exactly what I want and my SQL isn't too up-to-date.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The decimal will contain fractions of an hour ? and if so 0.5 means half an hour ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dateadd accept integers as second parameter, so fractions are truncated, in order to include them, just multiply with 60*60 and add seconds instead.

```
set @ScheduledEndDate = dateadd(ss, @EstimatedRequiredTimeHours * 3600, @ScheduledStartDate)
```

Comment: Thanks I saw that in your description after posting :P Really appreciate it.